# How to decrypt Jenkins 8mha values

Tags: java, encryption, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If we look at the Jenkins job logs, we can see that the text contained there, is exactly the same as what is displayed in the browser when you look into the Console Output **EXCEPT** for the URL that in the log files is encoded with something with the tag [8mha:

Does anyone know how can we "decrypt" it?

Already tried a simple base64 but it doesn't work.

This is one of those strings

```
[8mha:AAAAqR+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSajNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc+jsiC1KCczL9svvyTVzHb1RttJBUeZGJg8GdhyUvPSSzJ8GJhLi3JKGIR8shLLEvVzEvPS9YNLijLz0q0rihik0IxzhtAgwxgggJGJgaGiAMiQL2HQ0c/KT9J3zkhNzs4vLVE1MtAFYpfEkkQg5ZuYl5ieWgRkBbgF65sa6QMAtVXQDbEAAAA=[0m
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/LarrysGIT/Extract-Jenkins-Raw-Log/blob/master/README.md

Short answer here,

It's not encrypted, it still BASE64 string,

Example,

> Started by user
> [8mha:////4H+H6gi+RzqRXgbuxDkiDNvJYq3pMCu17+YXxGOB+mHbAAAAlx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzWEgZu/dLi1CL9xJTczDwAj6GcLcAAAAA=[0madmin

Can be split to the following parts,

`A string`: **Started by user**

`Preamble`: **\u001B[8mha:**

`Base64 string`: **////4H+H6gi+RzqRXgbuxDkiDNvJYq3pMCu17+YXxGOB+mHbAAAAlx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAzWEgZu/dLi1CL9xJTczDwAj6GcLcAAAAA=**

`Postamble`: **\u001B[0m**

`A string`: **admin**

Convert the base64 string to bytes, trim the first `40` bytes (https://github.com/LarrysGIT/Extract-Jenkins-Raw-Log/issues/1) and save as `.gz` file. Now you can extract real content from the `.gz` file.

In this case, the content is type `Java serialization data, version 5` following

> ¬í sr !hudson.console.ModelHyperlinkNote         xr
> hudson.console.HyperlinkNote6=«±=’pÅ I lengthL urlt
> Ljava/lang/String;xr hudson.console.ConsoleNote         xp   t
> /user/admin

Comment: Is that supposed to be "preamble"/"postamble"?  From what I can tell, "preamber"/"postamber" is not a word, and only appears on Google related to this post.

Comment: @M.Justin yeah, that is a typo. I didn't notice until your comment.

Answer (score 1):

That string is ansi-/ color-coded log output. To view the plain text version, you can utilize https://github.com/mmalecki/ansispan.
So, the given String

```
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] { (prepare)
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] }
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] // stage
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] stage
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] { (deployApplication)
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] }
    [8mha:AAAAaB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIwTG/KF0vKzUvOzOvODlTryCnNB3I0ivPL8pOy8kv18vKT9JLzs8rzs9J1QuHCgaV5jlDhPzyS1IZIICRiYGhoohBKqM0pTg/D64Hh8ICAFt0h+h/AAAA[0m[Pipeline] // stage
```

will result in

```
    [Pipeline] { (prepare)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (deployApplication)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
```