# How are Jenkins build log files encoded?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, encoding, jenkins-plugins

I find myself needing to read and analyze Jenkins build "log" files in a post-build step.  But I'm a bit unclear about the encoding used in these files.

Console output in the Jenkins webapp may look like this:
[image]

running `cat log` produces output like this:
[image]

In other words all the lines that show boldfaced in the Jenkins console do not appear at all with ordinary cat.

running `cat -vET log` produces output like this:

[image]

It looks as though two different encodings are being used in the same file.

Running `locale` tells me that the system is using en_US.UTF-8:

```
    $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I should say that all the "fancy formatted lines" were most likely produced by the Jenkins Gradle Plugin, since Gradle itself produces easily readable text.

Given that I want to write some code that will will read and analyze this file, how should that read it (what encoding, etc.)  as I want it to be read, that is, as an ordinary text file?

Comment: Like you mentioned, that colorized text is coming from gradle.  Jenkins is simply rendering that output for you.  I think you have 2 options: Update grade to produce just text output (no color or bold). OR run a script to strip those bold/color characters from the log, like this: https://superuser.com/questions/380772/removing-ansi-color-codes-from-text-stream

Comment: As I mentioned, this colorization does not occur when running gradle outside of jenkins.  So why blame gradle?  I believe the jenkins plugin for gradle is the more likely culprit.

Comment: If you're sure the gradle binary is not producing colorized output, then it is most likely the plugin injecting color and syntax: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gradle-plugin  For giggles, you can run a free style job and shell out the raw gradle commands and then examine the logs.  Like you, my bet is the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check here

[How to decrypt Jenkins 8mha values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635416/how-to-decrypt-jenkins-8mha-values)

Formed by `{PreAmber}{Base64Str}{PostAmber}`

`{Base64Str}` is compressed by `gzip`