# Jenkins get Build Log without the Color Encoding

Tags: jenkins, groovy, encoding, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to send the build log as an attachment post build but its not readable since alot of the text is encoded in base64 related: [How to decrypt Jenkins 8mha values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635416/how-to-decrypt-jenkins-8mha-values)

Since this jenkins instance is pretty much always in production i cannot install plugins or add dependencies. Is there anyway to get readable text from the jenkins log?

I read that you can make an API call to jenkins to get the text from the site, which i will try but after that i am pretty lost.

Any Jenkins masters have suggestions?

instead of
[8mha:AAAAqR+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSajNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc+jsiC1KCczL9svvyTVzHb1RttJBUeZGJg8GdhyUvPSSzJ8GJhLi3JKGIR8shLLEvVzEvPS9YNLijLz0q0rihik0IxzhtAgwxgggJGJgaGiAMiQL2HQ0c/KT9J3zkhNzs4vLVE1MtAFYpfEkkQg5ZuYl5ieWgRkBbgF65sa6QMAtVXQDbEAAAA=[0m

i am trying to get readable text like: Started by user ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out you dont need to decode it because the actual useful information is at the end. Solution: Define a regex pattern and matcher -> filter the string against that pattern and remove everything inside it.

Unfortunately retrieving the buildLog in the post step is not ideal because it doenst include all lines ...

```
def cleanLog(inputString) {
    def pattern = /\u001B\[8mha:(.*?)\u001B\[0m/
    def matcher = (inputString =~ pattern)

    def result = inputString

    while (matcher.find()) {
        def substringToRemove = matcher.group(0)
        result = result.replace(substringToRemove, "")
    }

    return result
}
```